# Django cms add page and to add plugin, when I Preview draft always show error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_app'

Tags: django, django-cms

Adding a plugin to a page gives an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_app'`.

This is my appplugin code:

```
class AppPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = 'app_plugin'
    model = AppInfo
    render_template = 'app_plugin.html'
    fields = ('title', 'size')

    @staticmethod
    def _add_app(para, project, context):
        count = App.objects.filter(
            name=para['name'], project_id=project).count()
        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This app already exists.'
        else:
            App.objects.create(
                name=para['name'],
                project_id=project
            )
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''

        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _modify_app(para, project, context):
        count = App.objects.filter(
            name=para['name'], project_id=project).count()
        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This app already exists.'
        else:
            app = App.objects.get(id=para['id'])
            app.name = para['name']
            app.save()
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''

        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _delete_app(para, project, context):
        try:
            app = App.objects.get(id=para['id'])
        except App.DoesNotExist:
            context['status'], context[
                'message'] = 'ERROR', 'Not found this app.'
            return context

        if app.testcase_set.count() or app.testsuite_set.count() or \
            app.testplan_set.count() or app.testexecution_set.count():
            context['status'], context[
                'message'] = 'ERROR', 'This app has been used.'
        else:
            app.delete()
            context['status'], context['message'] = 'SUCCESS', ''

        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _search_app(para, project, context):
        filter_param = {'project_id': project}
        app_name = para.get('app_name', None)
        if app_name:
            filter_param['name__icontains'] = app_name
            context['app_all'] = App.objects.filter(**filter_param).order_by(
                '-id')

        context['status'] = 'SUCCESS'
        context['message'] = ''
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _add_app_attr(para, project, context):
        count = AppAttr.objects.filter(
            name=para['name'],
            app_id=para['app_id'],
            project_id=project).count()

        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This attribute already exists.'
        else:
            AppAttr.objects.create(
                name=para['name'],
                app_id=para['app_id'],
                project_id=project
            )
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''

        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _modify_app_attr(para, project, context):
        count = AppAttr.objects.filter(
            name=para['name'],
            app_id=para['app_id'],
            project_id=project).count()
        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This attribute already exists.'
        else:
            attr = AppAttr.objects.get(id=para['id'])
            attr.name = para['name']
            attr.save()
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''

        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def _delete_app_attr(para, project, context):
        try:
            attr = AppAttr.objects.get(id=para['id'])
        except AppAttr.DoesNotExist:
            context['status'], context[
                'message'] = 'ERROR', 'Not found this attribute.'
            return context

        app = App.objects.get(id=attr.app_id)
        if app.testcase_set.count() or app.testsuite_set.count() or \
            app.testplan_set.count() or app.testexecution_set.count():
            context['status'], context[
                'message'] = 'ERROR', 'This attribute has been used.'
        else:
            attr.delete()
            context['status'], context['message'] = 'SUCCESS', ''
        return context

    def _operate(self, method, param, project, context):
        para = json.loads(param)
        return eval('self.' + method)(para, project.id, context)

    @check_login_required_flag
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        if not context['auth_flag']:
            return context

        config = AppInfo.objects.get(cmsplugin_ptr_id=instance)
        argpost = QueryDict.dict(context['request'].POST)
        project_name = context['request'].session['project']
        project = Project.objects.get(name=project_name)

        context['title'] = config.title
        context['size'] = config.size
        context['app_all'] = App.objects.filter(project_id=project.id).order_by(
            '-id')

        method = argpost.get('app_method', None)
        parameters = argpost.get('app_para', None)
        if method and parameters:
            context = self._operate(method, parameters, project, context)

        # paging processing
        app_list, page_range, entry_num = paginator(argpost, context['app_all'])
        app_detail = [{'app': app, 'attr': app.appattr_set.all()} for app in
                      app_list]

        context['app_detail'] = app_detail
        context['app_count'] = len(context['app_all'])
        context['entry_num'] = entry_num
        context['page_range'] = page_range
        context['app_list'] = app_list
        return context
```

Comment: ... and what would be the plugin code?

Comment: I'm sorry to replay so late,I have add my plugin code.thankyou!

Comment: two more pieces missing - the plugin HTML (app_plugin.html) and AppInfo model code.